# div not appearing below brother navbar div?

Tags: html, css, css-float, divider

I'm an amateur and I'm not sure why this div isn't appearing below the navbar div. The div i'm referencing is the `#sponsorBar` div.

Thanks for any help and let me know if I need to add any additional information.

```css
body {
  background-color:black;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#navBar {
  position:fixed;
  float:left;
  background-color:white;
  text-align:center;
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  top:0;
}

#navList {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color:white;
}

#navList li {
  float:left;
}

#navList li:nth-child(1) {
  border-left: 0;
}

#navList li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

#navList li:nth-child(5) {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

#navList li:nth-child(7) {
  border-right: 0;
}

#navList li a {
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  font-size:1.2em;
  vertical-align:-17px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:50px;
}

#navList li:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

#navList li:hover a {
  color:white;
}

.navImage {
  float:left;
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  max-height: 50px;
}
.navImage:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.navListItem_left {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width:100px;
}

.navListItem_right {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width:100px;
}

#sponsorBar {
  clear:left;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  background-color:white;
  height:100px;
  width:80%;
  margin:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <ul id="navList" class="navListItem">
    <li class="navListItem_left">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navListItem_left">
      <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navListItem_left">
      <a href="articles.html">Articles</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/index.html">
        <img src="img/simplify_black_transparent_500x500.gif" class="navImage"/>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="navListItem_right">
      <a href="menu5.html">Menu4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navListItem_right">
      <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navListItem_right">
      <a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--Sponsor Div-->
<div id="sponsorBar">
  <p style="color:red;">TEST</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abelgoodwin1988/a6tthq9k/

Comment: Remove position: fixed from #navBar .

Comment: What is your expected output? you `navbar` div is fixed div. So, give margin-top to `sponsorBar` will display below which you already done.

Comment: @VIVEKRAJ removing fixed from navBar doesn't solve the problem. I want the navBar to scroll down with the page.

Comment: @ketan I expect to have a navigation pane at the top that will scroll down with a long page whilest staying at the top. I want a div to appear just below the navBar that will not move when i scroll down.

Comment: Then it is working man. What is the issue?

Comment: @ketan Do you see a white div BELOW the navBar div? There's the white navBar div with the UL. There's nothing but the black <body> below that.

Comment: @ketan Thanks for trying to help, do you understand my problem?

Comment: Not yet. I can see `sponsorBar` below the `navbar`. http://i.stack.imgur.com/8w1dN.png

Comment: @ketan oh wow. What browser are you using? I've asked a few other people and they don't see it.. it should have "test" in red in it as well.

Comment: @ketan ok, so I just tested in IE and FF, works there but not in Chrome.. idea's?

Comment: Let me check in chrome. In FF it's work fine.

Comment: In chrome also same result. looks ok. I am using latest version of chrome. i.e. 50.0.2

Comment: @ketan interesting.. in my chrome "about": "Version 48.0.2564.116 m
 
Google Chrome is up to date."

Comment: This screenshot. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtRJh.png and this is version screenshot.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/9hjBh.png

Comment: @ketan very strange. It's working on IE and FF. But not my version of chrome, which claims it's up-to-date. I'll try and resolve this up-to-date issue (Guessing something to do w/ windows 10?)
http://imgur.com/3GG1ZLZ

Comment: May be but. It should work in that version also. Because. there is nothing like not working. Try to clear cache. Or. Reinstall chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow! that was super weird! for some reason JSFiddle didn't like the id "sponsorBar". I have no idea why. When I changed the id (and the corresponding CSS code) to sB it worked no problemo!!

https://jsfiddle.net/a6tthq9k/3/
HTML:

```
<body>
    <!--Navigation Div-->
    <div id="navBar">
        <ul id="navList" class="navListItem">
            <li class="navListItem_left">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navListItem_left">
                <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navListItem_left">
                <a href="articles.html">Articles</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/index.html">
                    <img src="img/simplify_black_transparent_500x500.gif" class="navImage"/>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navListItem_right">
                <a href="menu5.html">Menu4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navListItem_right">
                <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navListItem_right">
                <a href="partners.html">Partners</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--Sponsor Div-->
    <div id="sB">
        <p style="color:red;">TEST</p>
    </div>
    <!--Content Div-->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
        background-color:black;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    #navBar {
        position:fixed;
        float:left;

        background-color:white;
        text-align:center;

        height: 50px;
        width:100%;

        margin:0;
        padding:0;

        top:0;
    }

    #navList {
        display:inline-block;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color:white;
    }
    #navList li {
        float:left;
    }
    #navList li:nth-child(1) {
        border-left: 0;
    }
    #navList li:nth-child(3) {
        margin-right: 100px;
    }
    #navList li:nth-child(5) {
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
    #navList li:nth-child(7) {
        border-right: 0;
    }
    #navList li a {
        display:inline-block;
        font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:black;
        font-size:1.2em;

        vertical-align:-17px;

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

        height:50px;
    }

    #navList li:hover {
        background-color: black;
    }
    #navList li:hover a {
        color:white;
    }

    .navImage {
        float:left;
        display:block;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;

        max-height: 50px;
    }
    .navImage:hover {
        background-color: white;
    }

    .navListItem_left {
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        height: 50px;
        width:100px;

    }

    .navListItem_right {
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        height: 50px;
        width:100px;
    }

    #sB {
        clear:left;
        position:relative;
        display:block;

        background-color:white;

        height:100px;
        width:80%;

        margin:100px;
    }
```

Comment: Wow...
Same here.. It wasn't just JSFiddle, it was chrome.. wtffff? That is some weird shizz Keith.. Weird Shizz...

Comment: It was adblock! I just checked it and yup! sure enough when I turn it off it works fine!.